PaginatedDataTable Header and Footer Theme Configuration
I am making a PaginatedDataTable and the current code only colors the rows and the column headers

I want to be able to color the footer and header the same and the rows and column headers
Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
              //textTheme: const TextTheme(caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              dataTableTheme: DataTableThemeData(
                headingRowColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                    (Set<WidgetState> states) {
                  // Set color for heading row
                  return const Color.fromARGB(
                      255, 38, 44, 48); // example color
                }),
                dataRowColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                    (Set<WidgetState> states) {
                  // Set color for data rows
                  return const Color.fromARGB(
                      255, 38, 44, 48); // example color
                }),
                // Add other customizations here
              ),
            ),
            child: PaginatedDataTable(
              header: const Text('CSV Data',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              columns: columns,
              source: _DataSource(rows),
              rowsPerPage: rowsPerPage,
              onRowsPerPageChanged: (perPage) {
                setState(() {
                  rowsPerPage = perPage!;
                });
              },
              columnSpacing: 16.0,
              horizontalMargin: 16.0,
              showCheckboxColumn: false,
              arrowHeadColor: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),

I have tried different Theme wrapper configurations, but there are no options to directly style the footer and header

Was able to fix this by modifying the class PaginatedDataTable and adding widget level properties
I made a Issue and Pull Request on the Flutter library here
